# Getting the API by the callback function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have a function, that connects to the API and returns the data:

```
    import {API_KEY, API_URL} from "./constants";
    
    // /**
    //  * Fetch all tasks
    //  * @param {function} successCallback - Function that saves incoming data 
    //  */
export const getOperations = async (id, successCallback) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/tasks/${id}/operations`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: API_KEY,
        },
      });
  
      const data = await response.json();

  
      if (data.error) {
        throw new Error('Error!');
      }
  
      successCallback(data.data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Then, in one of my react component i call that function to get a data from the specified API:
The props is a required ID.

```
const [operations, setOperations] = useState([])
console.log(props)
useEffect(() => {
    try {
        getOperations(data => (props, setOperations(data)))
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}, [])
```

The problem is, that my API looks like:

```
`...api/tasks/function%20(data)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20props,%20setOperations(data);%20%20%20%`20%20%20%7D/operations`
```

So i receive 400 error.
Could someone explain me how to get API URL in this situation like:

```
/api/tasks/{id}/operations
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you defined your function as `getOperations = async (id, successCallback) ` but only call it with your callback function as the first argument, `getOperations(data => (props, setOperations(data)))`

Comment: you are sending your callback method to getOperations as parameter, you should send first parameter id, second parameter callback function.

Comment: Tbh, i don't get it, because as i can see in the code, fist argument is a id (props).

Comment: @OzanManav could u please show me how to call that function properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Rather than passing the callback to the result of the function, you could just return the data.

```
export const getOperations = async (id) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/tasks/${id}/operations`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: API_KEY,
        },
      });
  
      const data = await response.json();

  
      if (data.error) {
        throw new Error('Error!');
      }

      return data.data;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

useEffect(() => {
  async function apiCall() {
    try {
       const data = await getOperations(props.id);
       setOperations(data)
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }

  apiCall();
}, [props.id])
```